# How can i set OnClickListener inside Navigation Drawer item list of android studio.I am setting onClick listener but its not working

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

Code of MainActivity.java

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
       // View rootView;
       switch(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
            case 1:
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
                break;
            case 2:
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whatsnew, container, false);
                break;
```

Code of Fragment Class Home:

```
public class Home extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button OOverview,Programs,Admission,Faculty,Research,Beyond_Academics,Campus,
            Placement,Publication,Policies,Alumni,UGC,Notices,Media_Centre,Careers,Contact_us;


 View v;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,               Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.home,container,false);
    Programs=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnPrograms);
    Admission=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnAdmissions);
      //Setting onClick listener
     OOverview.setOnClickListener(this);
     Programs.setOnClickListener(this);
     Admission.setOnClickListener(this);


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btnOOverview:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"yghgheiufheief",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             /*Intent i=new Intent(this,Overview.class);
            startActivity(i);*/
            break;
```

Please Help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement this class in your actionbar activity class.

```
/**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }
```

implement displayView() method like below

```
/**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Log.e("displayView", "" + position);

        switch (position) {
            case 1:
                   //position one of drawer s clicked
             ...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)